# How can I make a listview transparent, but the items opaque?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview already transparent, however, I want the items to be opaque, how can I acheive that?

Here's my listview.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_list_left_border">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/product_info_list_colors"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20dp">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**: I can't set any background to the item, as I'm using a CircleImageView. Item XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_selected"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the background of layout, used for `ListView`'s item, opaque.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:padding="16dp">
</TextView>
```

**PS:** Layout of `ListView` items is used in `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of ListView Adapter to create view for items.

Comment: Can't do that, as I'm using a CircleImageView as item, if I do that, the images is now squared, I've edited my post.

Comment: That should work just fine. You don't need anything else. What are you trying to achieve? I would add couple extras suggestions: Use wrap_content for RelativeLayout's height, `orientation` is of no use in RelativeLayout. You should use [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for your use case instead of `ListView`.

Comment: If I set the background, it creates a colored square and the CircleImageView on top. I just want the CircleImageView to be opaque. Yeah, orientation is useless here, forgot to remove it. About the RecyclerView, I considered to use a ListView because there will be very few items to show. However, how's the RecyclerView gonna achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to make `CircleImageView` opaque? Is the image you are setting on it is not opaque? With `RecyclerView`, you won't have the default divider (which right now you need to make transparent), but it won't make much difference for you.

Comment: "What do you mean by you want to make CircleImageView opaque? Is the image you are setting on it is not opaque?" It's opaque, but because of the ListView is 30% transparent, the item is also 30% transparent.